# Prevent privilege-escalated js code in Firefox addon, iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon, code-injection

I have some code that is doing this to show a snippet of HTML from remote source.

```
respDiv.children[i].innerHTML = '<iframe type="content" src="about:blank" style="height:300px;width:100%;border:none;"/>';
respDiv.children[i].children[0].contentDocument.write('<style> * {font-size:12px;}</style>'+untrustedHTML);
```

The addon was rejected because of remote-code-injection, so I was wondering if there is any safe way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If your iframe is displaying a page from your extension and not a remote page, Then probably you should be using DOM construction methods to add elements. e.g.

```
respDiv.children[i].innerHTML = '<iframe type="content" src="about:blank" style="height:300px;width:100%;border:none;"/>';
```

changes to

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("type", "content");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "about:blank");
iframe.setAttribute("style", "height:300px;width:100%;border:none;");
respDiv.children[i].appendChild(iframe);
```

Similar code needs to be written for inserting the `<style>` element.

However if the frame's src refer to a remote page, the you might have a really tough time getting it approved because of security implications.

Comment: True, but unless this is in a loop the few nanoseconds wasted don't require rewriting. I know not to put remote urls in.

Answer (score -1):

Your extension was rejected because with your current code, there's no way for the reviewer to know (and no way for you to guarantee) that the content of `untrustedHTML` won't be something bad. It could contain a script that tracks the user, or steals their login, or worse.

The solution would be to use DOM methods to insert this content. This would ensure that you (and the reviewer) know the type of content that's going to be placed in that iframe. For example, if your extension was just inserting text, you could do:

```
respDiv.children[i].innerHTML = '<iframe type="content" src="about:blank" style="height:300px;width:100%;border:none;"/>';
respDiv.children[i].children[0].contentDocument.write('<style> * {font-size:12px; }</style>');
respDiv.children[i].children[0].contentDocument.appendChild(respDiv.children[i].children[0].contentDocument.createTextNode(textyouwanttoinsert));
```

If the content contains more elements than text, then you'll need to use DOM methods to create those as well. If untrustedHTML is really complex, you may have to parse it first then insert it with DOM methods; just make sure you have a limited list of things (elements, attributes, etc.) that you'd insert. Alternately, have your data source be JSON or XML or something, and translate from that to HTML. The point is, don't take HTML from your data source and place it in the web page.

Comment: But if I'm creating one text node, why use the iframe?

Comment: I don't know why you're using an iframe. If you're using it for some reason that would make my suggestion not work, please include this info and I'll revise the answer if necessary.

Comment: Actually you need to have a `data:` url so it doesn't inherit context of chrome window - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues